# compile error about transfer solidity

Tags: solidity

when i compile the following code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract SimpleAuctions {
    uint  public beneficiary; // 拍卖的受益人
    uint public auctionEnd; // 拍卖的结束时间
    address public highestBidder; // 当前的最高出价者
    uint public highestBid; // 当前的最高出价
    mapping(address => uint) pendingReturns; // 用于取回之前的出价
    bool ended; // 拍卖是否结束
    uint valueforbeneficiary;
    event HighestBidIncreased(address bidder, uint amount); // 出现新的最高价
    event AuctionEnded(address winner, uint amount); // 拍卖结束
    function SimpleAuction(uint[] valueforgoods) public pure {
        uint allvalue;
        uint i;
        for (i = 0;i < valueforgoods.length;i++){
            allvalue = allvalue + valueforgoods[i];

             if (valueforgoods[i] > highestBid) {  
                highestBid = valueforgoods[i];
            }
        }
    }
    function bid() public payable {
        require(
            now <= auctionEnd,
            "Auction already ended."
        );
        require(
            msg.value > highestBid,
            "There already is a higher bid."
        );
        if (highestBid != 0) {
            pendingReturns[highestBidder] += highestBid;
        }
        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        highestBid = msg.value;
        // beneficiary = allvalue;
        emit HighestBidIncreased(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function auctionEnd() public {
        require(now >= auctionEnd, "Auction not yet ended.");
        require(!ended, "auctionEnd has already been called.");
        ended = true;
        emit AuctionEnded(highestBidder, highestBid);
        beneficiary.transfer(highestBid);
    }
}
```

i come with :Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256 beneficiary.transfer(highestBid)".How to modify it?

Comment: Please translate code comments in english ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
uint  public beneficiary;
```

should be declared instead as address

```
 address public beneficiary;
```